# modify the list of object one of the property if found more then 1 record in a group in the list using java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have class Employee which have 3 fields.

And I have a list of DTO objects.

```
`public class Employee {
   private String empId;
   private String name;
   private String group;
   private String salary;
   private String incentive;         
}`

`List<Employee> listEmployees = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
 new Employee("101"."Mark", "A", 20000, 10),
 new Employee("102"."Tom", "B", 3000, 15),
 new Employee("103"."Travis", "C", 5000, 12),
 new Employee("104"."Diana", "D", 3500, 11),
 new Employee("105"."Keith", "B", 4200, 15),
 new Employee("106"."Liam", "D", 6500, 11),
 new Employee("107"."Whitney", "B", 6100, 15),
 new Employee("108"."Tina", "B",2900, 15)
 new Employee("109"."Patrick", "D", 3400, 11)
 ));`
```

I want to modify the **incentive of 5%** for all the employees in the same group, if there are more than one employee in a group. For example for above example there is more than one employee in the list of employee ***group B & D*** so in this case I want to modify the incentive to 5% for all the employees in the same group. But there is only one employee for ***group A & C*** so I don't modify anything for this employee.

For example any company decides to give incentive to employee every year, but if a department has more than a specific number (Example 100) of employees, they want to update the incentive value for all the employees in that same department. But other departments that have a specific number((Example 100)) of employees are less, so the incentive doesn't change.

I tried for example like :

`employeeList.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::group));`

So my result would be like below. (only A and C no need modify because only one record in this group)

```
`Employee("101"."Mark", "A", 20000, 10)
 Employee("102"."Tom", "B", 3000, 5),
 Employee("103"."Travis", "C", 5000, 12),
 Employee("104"."Diana", "D", 3500, 5),
 Employee("105"."Keith", "B", 4200, 5),
 Employee("106"."Liam", "D", 6500, 5),
 Employee("107"."Whitney", "B", 6100, 5),
 Employee("108"."Tina", "B",2900, 5)
 Employee("109"."Patrick", "D", 3400, 5)`
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What you're trying is totally valid, it gives you a map containing the lists that you can then check the length of. What you show as your result isn't what your collected stream gives you.

Comment: I want to update the incentive for all the employee in same group if any group have more the one employee.  For example: earlier group B have 15% incentive but in the group B have more then one employee so new incentive in new list 5% only.  So i want update the incentive property in the employee based on number of employee in same group have more then one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use `Collectors.groupingBy` to get the counts, then create a new `List` based on that.

```java
Map<String, Long> groupFreq = listEmployees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::group, Collectors.counting()));
List<Employee> result = listEmployees.stream().map(e -> {
    if (groupFreq.get(e.group()) > 1) 
        return new Employee(e.empId(), e.name(), e.group(), e.salary(), 5);
    return e;
}).collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList() in Java 16+
```

Comment: Side Note: e.empId() is Java 19 feature Record

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Employee> empList = listEmployees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGroup))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(v -> v.getValue().size() > 1)
            .flatMap(v->v.getValue().stream())
            .map(e ->new Employee(e.getEmpId(), e.getName(), e.getGroup(), e.getSalary(), 5))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!